# Piano Notation "T"?

Tags: piano, notation

I'm no high-end performer so probably won't matter but just curious what is this 'T'?

Second image has some notes of the first page, I supose the little schematic of the structure clarifies the T.
[image: Bach - BWV847 Fuga 2 - A 3 voci, bar 7]

[image: Note]

Comment: Does "T" appear elsewhere? Are any other letters like that used? Is there no editor comments/introduction explaining? What edition is this?

Comment: Yes, I also added the notes of the bottom of the page

Comment: I see. so "T" for "tema", and it seems it doesn't use "C" for "controsoggetto", etc.

Comment: Edition Breitkopf Nr. 2374. Only T appears but a couple of passages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly it denotes this is the main melody ('Theme') of the piece.   What piece is it?  Is that bit the same as the opening statement?

Comment: I can recognise the notes because I have practiced this piece recently. It is Bach fugue number 2 in c minor from the well tempered piano vol 1. And yes this it is the theme, so since it is in fact the theme it is probably why the publisher printed a T.

Comment: Is that sort of stating the obvious? Wouldn't a player maybe recognise what he's playing?

Comment: @Tim that's why most editions don't do this. :-)  If there are other fugues in the book (for example if it's the whole WTC or a larger subset of it), this suggestion should be very easy to test.

Comment: @phoog - or - is the engraver saying the 'theme' is in the l.h., judging by where the 'T' is?

Comment: @Tim yes.  If the engraver were saying anything else, the engraver would be wrong. Have a listen to it: you're right that most of the statements of the theme are completely obvious, but the first four notes of the theme often appear in sequential episodes without being a statement, and also the are a few statements that tend to sneak up on me so I'd mark them if I were learning it seriously: the soprano (major) in bar 11, the bass's final statement (m. 26) and perhaps the alto in the middle of the texture at bar 15. My conducting scores tend to have such marks no matter how obvious they are.

Comment: @phoog - since this is a piano transcription, the whole idea seems superfluous, don't you think?

Comment: @Tim it's a keyboard piece.  I wouldn't call it a "transcription."  The editor has changed the right hand clef from soprano to treble (standard practice in modern editions because nobody learns to read soprano clef these days) and added articulation marks, dynamics, and probably other expression and phrasing ideas, and these will be different for a piano than for a harpsichord, but the composer's explicit purpose is for the piece to be played on any keyboard instrument -- it's just that the modern piano didn't exist when he wrote it.

Comment: @phoog - it was just your hint towards a 'conductor'. For piano, or even harpsichord?

Comment: Since it's a fugue, it's a little non-standard to label a "theme". "Subject" is the word I would expect.

Comment: @ToddWilcox it might be nonstandard, but more likely it's [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuge_(Musik)).

Comment: @Tim I'm talking about conducting choral fugues, which I have far more experience with than playing keyboard fugues on any instrument.  So what I would or would not do in learning a keyboard fugue for performance is less certain than what I have done learning choral fugues.  Either way it can help to have redundant marks in the music for things you tend to forget. Surely you do this too from time to time?  Here the editor has done it for us.  It wouldn't be my first choice of edition, but it's not entirely unreasonable, especially if the edition is aimed at students or amateurs.

Comment: @phoog - I'm hardly into fugues of any sorts, as most of my answers portray, So, as far as that goes, my answers have not much bearing.

Comment: I don't think there's any doubt this marks the "thema," and it might be good for posterity to make the accepted answer more definite.

Comment: Does the "T" appear elsewhere? That should be a clue.

Comment: Yes, this marks the theme. It is used in the instructive edition by Bruno Mugellini from 1908 as well as 1952 edition by Pietro Montani. There is also an edition by Alessadro Longo which uses boxed numbers for the theme with the number being the number of the voice.

Answer (score -1):

This is the (first) entry of the third voice, so I expect it is "T for Tenor". (My copy of these fugues is covered with my own pencil S, A, T, B, so it looks rather familiar.) In principle I don't think the voices are named (could arguably be SAB, or even ATB), so it could possibly be T for "Third voice", but that seems very unlikely. If this is a book with all of the P&Fs, look for other similar indications, S, A, T or B.

Answer (score -2):

I'd hazard a guess at 'thumb'. Some older engravings used T, 1, 2, 3, 4 for fingering, rather than the modern 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, where 1 represents thumb. However, there appears '5' in the r.h., 1st and 2nd bars, and there's a suggested 2 under it, for index fingering. So **that isn't it**. It doesn't appear in any reference I possess, Dolmetsch being the go-to. However I'll leave this answer, as it may help later when fingering (notation) throws up a relevant question. Meanwhile, +1. Talking of which, I remember seeing thumb marked as **+**.

Maybe this ought to be a comment - powers that be..?

Comment: In addition to any other evidence against this guess is the fact that the note in question has a fingering of "2" below the staff.

Comment: @phoog - yes, I already mentioned that as a non-reason!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read very carefully.

Comment: I have never seen T for "thumb", but in what was called "English fingering" (as opposed to "Continental"), the signs were +1234, so that 1 meant your first finger.